# Php web browser

Tags: php, html

I have this code which should use the server to locate a web address and show it on the page. This is the best code i have and it doesn't work. i need it to use the server to get the website and show it on the page. there are also other supporting files which when you click a link on that new site continue to use your site.

How can i get this code to do what i need? 
Is there an alternative which i can use to sill use server-side instead of client side to bring up a web page?

[Full file](https://mega.nz/#F!sUAFyJTJ!0Fl-bkoEtfES4nR5tjjX2A)

index.php

```
<form action="main.php" method="post" name="URI" id="URI">
Enter URL you want the to browse:<br>
<input type="text" name="URI" size="40">
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

frameset.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['URI']) || !$HTTP_POST_VARS['URI']){
    header("Location: index.html");
    die;
}
$uri = urlencode($HTTP_POST_VARS['URI']);

$frameset = ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<!-- frames -->
<frameset  rows="8%,*">
    <frame name="php_browser_location" src="location.html" marginwidth="10" marginheight="10" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" noresize>
    <frame name="php_browser_main" src="main.php?php_browser_uri=$uri" marginwidth="10" marginheight="10" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
</frameset>

</html>

<?php ;
echo $frameset;

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure $frameset = ?>(...)<?php ; is working fine? Try to remove "$frameset = " and remove everything as well after the <?php

Comment: Wait, I'll write an answer because is well formatted

Comment: You do know that `$HTTP_POST_VARS [deprecated]`

Comment: I recommend to stop using framesets, this isn't 1999 anymore.

Comment: @Xorifelse But the party was fantastic wasn't it.

Comment: @Kamae all working fine. i think i found one problem in the index.html it posts to main.php instead of frameset.php.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It really was, and then [this](http://code.divshot.com/geo-bootstrap/) came... and so the party still continues

Comment: @Xorifelse Wow, that has to go on my Top 10 worst sites list

Comment: The url to the full file now working